# .htaccess rewrite for language subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need to configure subdomains on my website for multilanguage support.
I can set up the domains for local use pointing to a folder but my host does not allow me to point them to the main root where my app is

`/public/es`
`/public/www/index.php`

`es.domain.com` needs to point to `/public/www/index.php`

I can't even use symlinks in the `/es/` folder.

They replied to me

> For what concerns your hosting pack, we could suggest you to use the .htaccess and mod_rewrite tools.
> You could place an .htaccess file in your subdirectories to rewrite the  es.domain.com URL to domain.com/es/anything_else

In this way the visitor or search engine will still see

es.domain.com/anything as address.

I tried this is the `/es/` folder but get a 403

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^es.domain.com/?$   ^domain.com/es_ES?$ [L,R=301]   
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT** My site is set up to change the language using the `es.domain.com` subdomain.

Comment: I've read your question but I didn't understand. So correct me if I'm wrong. you have `es.domain.com` and you want all requests to it redirected to `domain.com`? right?

Comment: hi, no not redirected, rewritten. My host don't let me map subdomain to my main app in the www folder.

Comment: Sorry, I meant rewrite:-). So, for example `http://es.domain.com/index.php` goes to `http://domain.com/es_ES/index.php`? right?

Comment: `es.domain.com` needs to point to `/public/www/index.php` my app figures out the language from the subdomain port

Comment: is `/public/www/index.php` document root of your main domain?

Answer (score 7):

Here's what you may want to do, to be able to handle in the future many sub languages.

Check your host: if it begins with `es`, then change your **document root**.
Here's the tip:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.mydomain\.com$
# Change the path:
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php
```

---

And now something a little bit more advanced you may think about: multilanguage for the same website.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$
# Create an environment variable to remember the language:
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]

# Now check if the LANGUAGE is empty (= doesn't) exists
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
# If so, create the default language (=es):
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
```

Ok now we have an environment variable where the language is set.

You asked for this:

> `es.domain.com` needs to point to `/public/www/index.php`

So add this final rule:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^es$
# Change the root folder:
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php
```

So all in all:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$
# Create an environment variable to remember the language:
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
# Now check if the LANGUAGE is empty (= doesn't exist)
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
# If so, create the default language (=es):
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
# Change the root folder of the spanish language:
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^es$
# Change the root folder:
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php
```

---

What I don't get is: why can't you just write **once** for all languages, and make something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$
# Create an environment variable to remember the language:
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
# Now check if the LANGUAGE is empty (= doesn't exist)
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
# If so, create the default language (=es):
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]

# WHATEVER THE LANGUAGE ADD IT TO THE URI:
RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]
```

So now imagine someone types:

- `http://es.mydomain.com/`
- `http://us.mydomain.com/`
- `http://fr.mydomain.com/`
- `http://pt.mydomain.com/`

All point to **the same piece of code** and you just have to handle it in your `Php` file: look into the **`$_GET['language']`** variable and read the good "translation" file.

This is just an advice to help you making *less work* for a *very robust* application!

---

Hope this helps!

---

[Edit 1]

Here's the final stuff you may put into your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

[Edit 2]

My *latest* rules do this:

- `Original URL` =>  `where it goes`
- `http://pt.domain.com/       => http://pt.domain.com/?language=es`
- `http://pt.domain.com/aa.php => http://pt.domain.com/aa.php?language=es`
- `http://es.domain.com/       => http://es.domain.com/?language=es`
- `http://es.domain.com/aa.php => http://es.domain.com/aa.php?language=es`
- `http://domain.com/          => http://domain.com/?language=es`
- `http://domain.com/bb.php    => http://domain.com/bb.php?language=es`

It doesn't change the path **at all**.

This one changes the path:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php
```

So this should give:

- `Original URL` =>  `where it goes`
- `http://pt.domain.com/       => http://pt.domain.com/`
- `http://pt.domain.com/aa.php => http://pt.domain.com/aa.php`
- `http://es.domain.com/       => /public/www/index.php`
- `http://es.domain.com/aa.php => http://es.domain.com/aa.php`
- `http://domain.com/          => /public/www/index.php`
- `http://domain.com/bb.php    => http://domain.com/bb.php`

Comment: Wow thanks Oliver :-) I will check it out tomorrow. These rules go into the sub folders right? For each language. Your last code block is to put in the /www/ folder where my app is, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer so that you get, at the end, the full rewrite rule you just copy/paste to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Hi I just checked it out but I get a 403, Forbidden. I also wanted note that I updated my CMS to a version where it figures out localization by the subdomain, so it's not necessary anymore to link to `domain.com/es_ES/` anymore. `es.domain.com` should just point to `/public/www/index.php`

Comment: When I try your first code block `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|fr|pt|es)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} !^$
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:es]
RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^es$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /public/www/index.php` I get a 404, Not Found

Comment: Are you sure that `/public/www/index.php` exists?

Comment: Hi Oliver, yes that's the content when visiting domain.com Looks like the .htaccess in the /es/ folder can't make the jump to the /www/ folder.

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems I don't get the whole stuff. I'm editing my answer so that you can see (at the end of my answer) how, maybe, you could explain what works, what doesn't, and why it doesn't i.e. how it should work. I've edited and corrected a mistake (test if empty = `^$` not `!^$`) !!

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (us|fr|pt)\.mydomain\.com$` to allow
www.(us,fr,pt).mydomain.com as well.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^es\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://domain.com/es_ES/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I get a 404 "The requested URL /es_ES/ was not found on this server." I need to get to mydomain.com/es_ES/

Comment: Also when I try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /albums/$1 [L]` I get a 500 - domain.com/albums/ is a valid URL in my `/public/www/` directory

Comment: Sorry. I assumed that the subdomain was in the same vhost. I missed that part in your question. I edited my solution above!

Comment: Gerben, thanks so much for the help. Unfortunately it doesn't work yet.. I get a 404. Even hhen I do `RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://domain.com/$1 [P,L]` I get a 400 "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit."